# python user input error int vs string

Tags: python, input

I tried to search for this error, but i didnt find it so here it is:

I try to enter input in a python 3 script running in linux, which can only be 0-5.
I do this using the following code:

```
    while True:
        type = input("Please choose a type:\n1) a\n2) b\n3) c\n4) d\n0) EXIT\n"))

        if type == "0":
            sys.exit()

        elif type == "1" or type == "2" or type == "3" or type == "4":
            print("You entered: %s" %type )
            break

        else:
            os.system("clear")
            print("Input entered is invalid, please try again.\n")
```

The program runs fine when I enter numbers, but when I enter a letter it crashes.
Please help :(

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    type = input("Please choose a type:\n1) a\n2) b\n3) c\n4) d\n0) EXIT\n"))   
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'h' is not defined
```

Comment: you should not use 'type' as a variable name because you are overriding the builtin function

Comment: Your code and the traceback don't match. The last line of the traceback says "name 'h' is not defined" but I don't see any 'h' in your code.

Comment: @F.C. : h is the typed input, which is evaluated by `input`, which doesn't find it to be evaluable, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`

Meaning your input is interpreted. Meaning that number, function, var will work, but not text.

Use `raw_input` instead. (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input )

Nota: this is valid python 2, and you mention python 3. However, I think you are actually using python 2, as your prompt ends with a \n, which is included in python 3, and as your script works on python 3

Comment: Thanks, it seems linux runs 2.x by default, when i need to use python 3. I dont want to use the python 2 variants however, i need to install python 3 on linux :)

Comment: @MrFronk Most modern linux distros will have python 3 installed as well - generally with the command `python3`.